# Django, Docker, Python - Unable to install Pillow on python-alpine

Tags: python, django, docker, python-imaging-library

I have a dockerized django app that I want to put in production. But ever since I added an Imagefield Pillow is required and I struggle to install Pillow in the Docker container.

As far as I understand it, adding the dependencies jpeg-dev ibjpeg & zlib-dev should be enough for django (?). With the configuration below I receive the error:

**Error on `runserver`:**

```
product.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
product.Product.thumbnail: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".
```

**If I add Pillow to requirements.txt (or putting `pip install Pillow` in the Dockerfile) I get an even longer error message while trying to build the container.**

Without putting `pip install Pillow` in Dockerfile or requirements.txt - this is my configuration.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/kitschoen-dj

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps
    && apk add jpeg-dev \
    && apk add libjpeg \
    && apk add zlib-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/kitschoen-dj/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/kitschoen-dj/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/kitschoen-dj/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/kitschoen-dj/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
astroid==2.1.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.1.7
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-filter==2.1.0
djangorestframework==3.9.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==3.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
httpie==1.0.2
httpie-jwt-auth==0.3.0
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
Markdown==3.0.1
mccabe==0.6.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.1
wrapt==1.11.1
```

I have been stuck with this for a while. Can someone help?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in what worked for me (+ some background on why I ran into this):

Installing Pillow will require several dependencies. As far as I can tell, you need: `gcc python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev`

To prevent these dependencies from ending up in the final image (keeping the image-size small) you can install some (not all!) of them in a virtual package.

After Pillow is installed successfully you can delete the dependencies that are only required for Pillow's installation.

Dependencies that are only needed during the build are called `build dependencies`.

So this is the code that worked for me:

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg \
    && pip install Pillow \
    && apk del build-deps
```

(Some of the stuff is not required for Pillow, e. g. postgressql, postgresql-dev). As you can see, I installed my build dependencies in a virtual package called `build-deps`. AFTER installing the build dependencies, I am installing Pillow. At the end, I am removing the build dependencies.

I think, this is the solution that @LinPy proposed: I just wanted to explain this in a very verbose way to help others.

[What is .build-deps for apk add --virtual command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221063/what-is-build-deps-for-apk-add-virtual-command)

Comment: Why do you have postgresql in here? Is it needed for Pillow?

Comment: "As far as I can tell, you need..." please read the original post.

Comment: Also, I literally wrote in my post: "(Some of the stuff is not required for Pillow, e. g. postgressql, postgresql-dev)"

Comment: All seems good. I found I needed `libc-dev` too but I didn't have `musl-dev`

Answer (score 22):

add this to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps build-base linux-headers \
    && pip install Pillow
```

source: [Github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1763)

Comment: Thank you your input led me in the right direction! Not to say your solution doesn't work ... but it increases image size by about 120MB which is quite a lot.

Comment: True, I think your solution is correct. What was missing for me (since I am still learning a lot of stuff, was that I have to delete the .build-deps in a later step for them to not end up in the image. But I like the usage of the meta-package build-base. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Pillow needs zlib-dev and jpeg-dev as build dependecies which can be removed. But it will also need libjpeg while running. So you could use something like this for a minimal image:

`RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers zlib-dev jpeg-dev && apk add libjpeg && pip install Pillow --no-cache-dir && apk del .tmp`

Answer (score 6):

I just added these lines to my Dockerfile and it worked

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk del .tmp
```

---

My Dockerfile (using python:3.8-alpine):

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Docker file

`RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev`

Answer (score 0):

#Docker file
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /app

## set environment variables

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

## install psycopg2 dependencies

RUN apk update 
&& apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev libc-dev make git libffi-dev openssl-dev  libxml2-dev libxslt-dev  zlib-dev jpeg-dev

## install dependencies

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

## copy project

COPY . .

## Requirement file

`Pillow==9.0.0`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would suggest you take a look at [the formatting how-to guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make your code be beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked for me

```
FROM python:3.9.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN mkdir /backend
ADD ./app /backend

WORKDIR /backend


RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual .tmp gcc python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev musl-dev libjpeg py3-setuptools \
    tiff-dev openjpeg-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev \
    libwebp-dev tcl-dev tk-dev harfbuzz-dev fribidi-dev libimagequant-dev \
    libxcb-dev libpng-dev alpine-sdk build-base openssl-dev dateutil tzdata py3-tz && \
    
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    echo 'requirements Installed' && \
    pip install uvicorn gunicorn  && \

    apk del .tmp



ENV DB_NAME  ******
ENV DB_USER ******
ENV DB_PASSWORD ******

ENV DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD ******

CMD gunicorn myproject.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```