# Can't access argon2 in Alpine Linux / Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux, argon2-cffi

I'm installing argon2 for Python with `RUN apk add py3-argon2-cffi`.
This installs the Python argon2 package from Alpine (https://alpine.pkgs.org/3.14/alpine-community-x86_64/py3-argon2-cffi-20.1.0-r1.apk.html).
When I try to import it with `import argon2` I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argon2'
```

I don't want to install argon2 with `pip` because I don't have `gcc` installed.
`gcc`would tripple my container size and I need a small container so I tried to use the Alpine argon2 package.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Are you 100% you don't have a python2 and python3 version living on the container? I cannot reproduce from my side from `alpine:latest` if I do `apk add py3-argon2-cffi py3-six` then `python3` and `import argon2`, all works.

Comment: Also note that, on Alpine, you can easily add a meta virtual package for packages that are just there at build time then remove them later (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221063/what-is-build-deps-for-apk-add-virtual-command)

Comment: With `alpine:latest` it works but not with `python:alpine`. I thought that `python:alpine` is `alpine:latest` with preinstalled python, pip, etc..

Comment: I've switched to `alpine:latest` and even redurced my image sice further.
Thank you so much - it is workig.